# Regex - redirect from website.com to website.com/us and append substring

Tags: regex, url, redirect

Can anyone help me correct my regex?

My hosting provides IP geolocation and I want to redirect US clients to another sub-directory of my website.

The website runs on a Nginx server and the hosting provides an interface where one can add redirection rules. The interface consists of Domain, Redirect from, Redirect To, Traffic from (country) and HTTP status code 301 or 302.

Example:
for all non-US clients `website.com/blog/article/really-good-book`
only for US clients `website.com/us/blog/article/really-good-book`

I currently have:
Redirect from `^/(?!us/)(.*)$`
Redirect to `/us/$1`

This currently redirects me to `website.com/us/index.php` and nothing else. So the redirect is applied, it only appends index.php instead of blog/article/really-good-book.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include where these regular expressions will be used, i.e. is this an Apache config or similar? Show the smallest configuration that fails.

Comment: It is hard to answer your question without knowing where do you put the redirection rules.

Comment: @MichaelC. I updated my question with information around the interface that I use.

Comment: @DeanTaylor It's a Nginx config, so I don't have access to a .htaccess file. I started with a minimal Redirect from `^.*$` to `/us`which left me in redirection hell. From there I tried to ignore all urls which already have "us" in them and to append everything else otherwise to the new url.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found my own solution:
Redirect from `^(?!(/us|/index.php|/wp-admin|/wp-login.php))(.*)$`
Redirect to `/us/$1`

I also added a rule for my wordpress backend, otherwise it would always redirect me back to `website.com/us` while trying to access `website.com/us/wp-admin`.